# Upload a .png image to each generated .pdf document

Tags: python, fpdf

I have created a code that looks to read each of the images in a folder and uploads each image to a separate .pdf document, (I have 5 .png images, so 5 .pdfs should be generated).

```
import pandas as pd
import os

Data = {'Joint': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Cx': [0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]}
PlanData = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Data)

from fpdf import FPDF

for i in PlanData.index:
    
    Joint = PlanData['Joint'][i]
    
    pdf = FPDF(orientation='P', unit='mm', format='A4')
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font('Arial', 'b', 8.5)
    pdf.text(x=10,y=10, txt='Proyect:')
    
    folder_dir = "C:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/Tests" #You can change the location with the attached folder in the link.
    for images in os.listdir(folder_dir):
     
        if (images.endswith(".png")):
            print(images)
            pdf.image(str(images), x=20, y=20, w=165, h=27.5)

    pdf.output('Doc'+str(int(Joint))+'.pdf')
```

The problem is that when executing my code, for each document that is generated, only the last image is loaded. I'm almost close to solving it, but if someone can help me, or has a better programming idea, I'd really appreciate it.

I attach my documentation to run the script [here](https://utpl-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/davillarreal1_utpl_edu_ec/EWbMojF5UPVKoPyv_6N7KTcBewoa3oOWkSBd4c6TTND34w?e=vBE6pE)

Comment: hi, perhaps create and save the pdf within the loop that handles each image?

Comment: @jspcal Could you please detail your solution? Thank you

Comment: You're putting all images in the same page at the exact same position, so unsurprisingly only the last one is visible.

Comment: Exactly, the error goes there. But how could I modify the code to give solution. Thanks in advance, @Olivier